# An inequality involving norm of vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $U \subset M$ open, $f : U \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism and $Df_x : T_x M \to T_{f(x)} M$, $x \in M$. Let $\lambda < 1 < \mu$ and for every $x \in M$, consider a $(\lambda, \mu)$-splitting such that 
$T_x M = E^u_x \bigoplus E^s_x$ and 
$$ \| {Df_x}_{|E^s_x} \| \leq \lambda, \;\;  \|({Df_x}_{|E^u_x})^{-1} \| \leq \mu^{-1}.$$
Let $v := \xi + \eta$, $\xi \in E^u_x$, $\eta \in E^s_x$, such that $\| \eta \| \leq \gamma \| \xi \|$, $\gamma > 0$ small enough.

I have to show that $$\| Df_x v \| \geq \frac{\mu}{1+\gamma} \| \xi \|.$$

My work: $\| Df_x v \| = \| Df_x \xi + Df_x \eta \| \leq \| Df_x \xi \| + \| Df_x \eta \| \leq \| Df_x \| \| \xi \| + \| Df_x \| \| \eta \|$.

and
$$\| Df_x \| \| \xi\| \geq \mu \| \xi \|, \;\;\; \| Df_x \| \| \eta\| \leq \lambda \| \eta \| \leq \lambda \gamma \| \xi \| \leq \mu \gamma \| \xi \| .$$

From here, I don't know how to continue. Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First comment: You should be writing $\|Df_x|_{E^u_x}\|$, $\|Df_x|_{E^s_x}\|$ where they belong.

If $\gamma>0$ is small enough so that $\mu\ge \lambda(1+\gamma)$, then you win. 
Let $A=(Df_x)|_{E^u_x}$. We are given that $\|A^{-1}\|\le 1/\mu$. So $\|\xi\| = \|A^{-1}(A\xi)\|\le \|A^{-1}\|\|A\xi\| \le \frac1{\mu}\|A\xi\|$, from which we conclude that $\|A\xi\|\ge \mu\|\xi\|$. Now we proceed, using the reverse triangle inequality:
$$\|Df_x(v)\| \ge \|(Df_x)|_{E^u_x}(\xi)\|-\|(Df_x)|_{E^s_x}(\eta)\| \ge \mu\|\xi\|-\lambda\gamma\|\xi\| = (\mu-\lambda\gamma)\|\xi\|.$$
Now just check that if $\mu\ge \lambda(1+\gamma)$, then $\mu-\lambda\gamma\ge\dfrac{\mu}{1+\gamma}$.

Comment: I don't understand the second inequality $$\|(Df_x)|_{E^u_x}(\xi)\|-\|(Df_x)|_{E^s_x}(\eta)\| \ge \mu\|\xi\|-\lambda\gamma\|\xi\| .$$ Can you give me more details? Thank you!

Comment: These are just two of the (correct) inequalities you had listed (taking the negative of one of them).

Comment: But $\| {Df_x} _{| E^u_x} \xi \| \leq \|{ Df_x} _{|E^u_x }\| \| \xi \| \geq \mu \| \xi \|$.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll edit the answer.